# SAS : ODS and code highlighting

Tags: sas

When using R markdown for making statistical reports, I have the ability to echo the R code in my output document. I'm learning SAS and I was wondering if it was possible to highlight or echo the SAS code in my final ODS report ? I'm using a dirty hack right know to display the code in my document, which is using "ods text = ", but it seems quite redundant. Plus it doesn't add syntax highlighting.

Comment: Unfortunately that feature does not exist. However you can use use Jupyter Notebooks to have a similar feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature does not exist in the SAS language right now, but it has been mentioned in several talks by [Amy Peters](https://blogs.sas.com/content/author/amypeters/), principal product manager of the SAS programing environments, as a planned feature for a near-future SAS release (with no specific date yet, but hopefully in the next 2 years).  It would likely be implemented in a similar fashion to Jupyter Notebooks, in that you write your code and get your output inline.

That said, SAS does support [Jupyter Notebooks](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2016/04/24/how-to-run-sas-programs-in-jupyter-notebook/), which is the best current (third party) solution.  Contact your SAS administrator for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I'll go for this as this feature requires SAS 9.4 (which I have)

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea here, I'm the type of guy who dosent take no for answer and find a way to fiddle and get it done... but i think this is abit far fetch... you can try still I think it will work with mostly evrything but may have a hard time to play with quotes when you have multiple semi colomns....
Check:
I started by creating a dumbass dataset :

```
data tata;
x=1;
run;
```

then we do the following:

```
%let code= select * from tata;

proc sql;
create table report as 
&code.;
quit;

proc print data=report;
footnote "&code.";
run;
```

The rationale:
I think it you put your code in macrovariables and then execute those macro variables you would be able to print show the code after by printing the macrovariable following your text...
See the sample